# hover effects on image like appears a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my html code:

```
               <div class="wrapper"> 
                <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
                <img  data-src="holder.js/180x180" style="height:20%;width:100%;float:left;"
                src="../goyal/profile-pic.jpg" alt="Klematis">
               </a><p class="text">gjhgkuhgfkuyfrjytdcj</p>
               </div>
```

css:

```
 #wrapper .text {
position:relative;
bottom:30px;
left:0px;
visibility:hidden;
}

#wrapper:hover .text {
visibility:visible;
}
```

This is my profile picture of my page. 
when i hover on image it shows a button and some
text with opacity.
like edit profile picture etc 
you can use jQuery code.

Demo [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/xxyjD/)

Comment: you want a button show on hover in image

Comment: Just a hint for future, when you're showing an image in your demo you need to use an absolute URL (JS Fiddle doesn't host your images, they're on *your* server if you're using relative URLs). If you don't want to link to your own server then consider using [Placekitten.com](http://placekitten.com), or [lorempixel.com](http://lorempixel.com) (among others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also achieve that with opacity and CSS3 Transitions, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/bVnRj/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <a target="_blank" href="klematis_big.htm">
    <img  data-src="holder.js/180x180" style="height:20%;width:100%;float:left;"
  src="../goyal/profile-pic.jpg" alt="Klematis"/>
  </a>
  <p class="text">Text Text Text ...</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper .text {
  position:relative;
  bottom:30px;
  left:10px;
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

.wrapper:hover .text {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 #wrapper .text {
```

with

```
 .wrapper .text {
```

And

```
#wrapper:hover .text {
```

with

```
.wrapper:hover .text {
```

`wrapper` is an `class` not an `id`.`id` will represented with `#` and class will represented with `.`

Comment: Have a demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xxyjD/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xxyjD/1/).